# angularjs can't find "this" by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, events, angularjs-ng-click

for example, I have two buttons

```
  <button class="item" ng-click="clickFun(this)">ngClick</button>
  <button class="item" onClick="clickFun(this)">jQueryClick</button>
```

I was trying to access two buttons, it works in jQuery Click, but ngClick is failed. I got '(empty)' from ngClick.

js code:

```
var oneApp = angular.module('oneApp', [])
.controller('oneCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log('running');
  $scope.clickFun = function(obj){
     console.log($(obj).text());
    //console.log($(obj).next('.next'));
    //console.log($(obj).next('.next').text());
  }
});

function clickFun(obj){
  console.log($(obj).text());
}
```

Here is my demo: http://codepen.io/dotku/pen/VjwEvR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass `$event` object while calling `ng-click` function which will basically pass current event object to `clickFun` & then do `event.target`, that will indicate current context(`this`) inside controller.

**Markup**

```
<button class="item" ng-click="clickFun($event)">ngClick</button>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.clickFun = function(event){
   console.log($(event.target).text());
}
```

[**Working CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NrWOgd)

> **Note**: Playing with DOM inside controller isn't correct way in Angular

Answer (score 0):

Passing a DOM element to a callback function is not the Angular way. It is the jQuery way.

In Angular there is no need to pass a DOM element, because the Angular way is not to do DOM manipulation, but model manipulation; and the view may bind to the model.

So in Angular you would pass a reference to a model property, not a DOM element:

```
<button class="item" ng-click="clickFun(somethingToClickOn)">ngClick</button>
```

which would pass $scope.somethingToClickOn to the click handler, identifying what field you want to pass/manipulate by clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think  `this` has any meaning in the html. You can instead pass `$event` in the function and use `$($event.current).text()` instead as:

```
<button class="item" ng-click="clickFun($event)">ngClick</button>
```

and in JS write:

```
 $scope.clickFun = function(event){
     console.log($(event.target).text());
  }
```

See the updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yJLRXP)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by $event

```
 <button class="item"  ng-click='functionname($event)'>
```

Regards,
Selvam.M